# create chain from abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have an assignment so I'm not really looking for someone to solve it, just want to understand what's actually requested because I feel like it's poorly worded.

```
1. Please implement the function described in the comment of this incomplete code snippet



// AudioEffect is the base class for effects that can process
// audio and have a subsequent effect (next).
struct AudioEffect {
virtual ~AudioEffect() = default;
virtual void process(float* buf, size_t num) = 0;
std::shared_ptr<AudioEffect> next;
};
// Implement a function that checks if there is a feedback loop
// in the effects chain.
... detect_feedback(...)
{
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like a question targeted to the author of that assignment and not us.

Comment: couldn't agree more, but that's not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The only loop I can see accuring is in the pointer chain.

So you will have to follow the `next` pointer and make sure that you never meet the same effect twice.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this explanation, because I also believe it's a linked list.

Comment: but I guess I would need to implement a child class to add a parameter that would be checked for effect type, right?

Comment: @freddo I do not think, that you need a child class. One simple (maybe stupid) way is to have list of pointers. In every step you get the address of the current effect and check if it is allready in the list. If so, then you have a loop. Otherwise you add the address to the list and procedd with the effect referenced in `next`. If there is no effect in `next` the function terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You are to check if the given graph is cyclic.

The function arguments should be a container of `std::shared_ptr<AudioEffect>` objects. Returning bool.

For each element in the container, use BFS or DFS to traverse the graph. Each node should be combined with an indicator, whose value is 0 at first and becomes 1 after visited. The program should check the indicator before visiting a node. If it is 1, then the graph is cyclic. You can throw an exception or break the loop to exit the search.

You must be learning data structures and algorithms. Go for it!

Comment: thanks for the encouragement! Is it a graph though? because I had the impression that it was a linked list. I could easily be wrong though.

Comment: @freddo Sorry, you're right. It's a single-linked list. But the algorithm above also fits.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a linked list of effects, then traverse the list and check the use_count of each shared pointer. If it's more than 2, then feedback exists.